# Java - "invalid stream header" with Serialization of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, serialization, arraylist

I have a trouble with my java project. After several searches, i'm still blocked.

I have a class named `ListFromFile` that extends `ArrayList` :

```
public class ListFromFile<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Serializable {

    private String listFile;

    public ListFromFile() {
        this.listFile = null;
    }

    public ListFromFile(String file) {
        this.listFile = file;
    }

    public void loadDataFromFile() { // Deserialize from file

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(this.listFile);

            if ( fileInput.read() == -1 ) { // If file is empty
                this.saveDataInToFile();
            } else {
                ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);

                this.addAll((ArrayList) objectInput.readObject());

                objectInput.close();
            }

            fileInput.close();
        } catch ( IOException | ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveDataInToFile() { // Serialize the ArrayList
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(this.listFile, true);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);

            objectOutput.writeObject(this);

            objectOutput.flush();
            objectOutput.close();
            fileOutput.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In my main class `BZ2MServer`, i've created some objects with ListFromFile :

```
public class BZ2MServer {

    private static ListFromFile<Specialite> specialites = new ListFromFile<Specialite>("liste_specialites.txt");
    private static ListFromFile<Module> modules = new ListFromFile<Module>("liste_modules.txt");
    private static ListFromFile<Professeur> professeurs = new ListFromFile<Professeur>("liste_professeurs.txt");
    private static ListFromFile<Etudiant> etudiants = new ListFromFile<Etudiant>("liste_etudiants.txt");
    private static ListFromFile<Note> notes = new ListFromFile<Note>("liste_notes.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        specialites.loadDataFromFile();
    }
}
```

When the application starts, it loads the lists saved in files. That's why i execute `saveDataInToFile()` inside that `loadDataFromFile()` method.
By this way, the files should contain empty ArrayList at the first time we launch the application.

The result is that for the first launch, there is no issue. However, after this, i always have this from the compiler :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ED000573
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at bz2m.list.ListFromFile.loadDataFromFile(ListFromFile.java:31)
    at bz2m.server.BZ2MServer.main(BZ2MServer.java:22)
```

I have tested this in the main of `BZ2MServer`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Specialite test = new Specialite(1, "Test");

    specialites.add(test2);

    specialites.saveDataInToFile();
}
```

Then, i removed the previous code, used `LoadDataFromFile()` to get the previous datas. And i got the error. Then, i removed that condition in `ListFromFile` class :

```
if ( fileInput.read() == -1 ) {
    this.saveDataInToFile();
}
```

And it worked. However, that condition was necessary in the case the file is empty. Without it, and if the file is empty, i get this :

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at bz2m.list.ListFromFile.loadDataFromFile(ListFromFile.java:31)
    at bz2m.server.BZ2MServer.main(BZ2MServer.java:22)
```

I hope that i have give you all the information you need to help me. If you need, i can upload the entire project (not huge).

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The serialization methods you're using includes a [magic number verification check](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readStreamHeader%28%29) that it uses to determine whether your data is valid or not.  So if it's anything other than what it expects, it will throw an exception telling you that your input does not conform to its serialization standards.

In this case, it expects the first two bytes to be `AC ED` followed by a version `00 05`. You can see them in the list of constants [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC).

The `invalid stream header: ED000573` indicates that the first 4 bytes of the input that it received is `ED 00 05 73`. If you open it in a hex viewer, you might actually be confused: the first bytes starting at position 0 is indeed `AC ED 00 05`, so what's the problem?

The reason why your load method fails is precisely because of that check you made:

```
if ( fileInput.read() == -1 ) {
    this.saveDataInToFile();
}
```

This reads one byte, which increments the file pointer to the second byte in the file. Now when you pass your stream to the `ObjectInputStream` for loading, it will read the first 4 bytes from where the current pointer is, see `ED 00 05 73` and then fail. You can verify this yourself by looking at the next byte after in your viewer.

If you want to check whether your file is not empty, instead of reading a byte to check whether there are bytes or not, just query the channel for its length directly:

```
if (fileInput.getChannel().size() == 0) {
    // empty file
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much MxyL ! 

`fileInput.getChannel().length` doesn't exist, so i used `fileInput.getChannel().size()`, then it works perfectly :)

Comment: Is it bad to use `if ( fileInput.available() == 0 )` instead of `if ( fileInput.getChannel().size() == 0 )` ?

Comment: Oops it is `size()` not `length` I usually get those two mixed up. `available` in this situation should be fine. I just don't really like how it sounds from the description.